# Caliburn micro action on model-object

Tags: c#, wpf, caliburn.micro

Using [caliburn micro](https://caliburnmicro.com/) you can execute a method by  doing this:

```
<Buttton x:Name="ClickMe" />
```

and in the`ViewModel` have a method like this:

```
public void ClickMe() 
{
    //Method will be execute upon button click
}
```

Is it possible to bind this to a method inside a property in the `ViewModel`? Like this?:

```
<Buttton x:Name="Model.ClickMe" />
```

Comment: That's *not* an event handler, it's the name of an [action](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/actions). The action and elements are bound using by triggers. The concept is the same as data binding. No matter what input control you use, the same command can be called when that control is triggered. You can also bind *multiple* view controls to the same command

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for you contribution. Not really sure what you are trying to say here, but it seems to me that this is not related to the caliburn.micro framework? Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Quite the opposite. The link points to the Caliburn.Micro documentation which explains the naming convention is used to create triggers that call actions in response to events, how they bubble and how you can use the Message.Attach syntax. What you're looking for is the syntax to bind to another ViewModel object.

Comment: I'd suggest this is a *strange* requirement. A ViewModel is meant to serve a view. It's not a code-behind file nor a domain model. Why would a view trigger an action on a nested viewmodel? Not that it can't be done - worst case, you write the entire `Trigger` element. It's far easier if a View triggers actions on its own ViewModel though

Comment: Again thanks! I misunderstood you. I find it strange to have a method in my viewmodel which just calls the models object.

Comment: Caliburn.Micro, and WPF in general, allows [composition](https://caliburnmicro.com/documentation/composition). You can have a view with nested views, that bind to one ViewModel and nested ViewModels rather easily. Elements in a child view should trigger actions in their own viewmodels

Comment: Imagine you have a master/detail view for example. That's a root view, with a master list and a detail view. These can (and should) map to a ViewModel that contains a Master ViewModel and a Detail ViewModel. Doing so is almost trivial in Caliburn.Micro - just use a `ContentControl` for each of the child views in the root view and Caliburn.Micro will pick the correct view for the Master and Detail VMs based on their names. Once you do that, UI elements in the *detail* will call actions in the detail VM itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First thing when you write the following:

```
<Button x:Name="Model.ClickMe" />
```

Who will give you an error like:

> 'Model.ClickMe' is not a valid value for property 'Name'.

Now if you want to call another method inside another `UserControl` (your `Model`), you need to bind to that model.

```
   <Button x:Name="ClickMe" cal:Bind.Model="{Binding Model}"></Button>
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks alot!